# setting xml file path in web.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net

My XML file resides in the `App_Data` folder of my asp.net project. I want to set the path of my XML file in the `web.config` file so that it can be accessed in my class libraries. I want it because when I move my project to our university computer it makes problem. Please anybody help me write the code in `web.config` file and also C# code through which it can be accessed.

Also I should mention I have googled this topic and also searched on stack overflow but nothing matched my case

Comment: add a key in the AppSettings

Comment: please can u write how to do this

Comment: www.google.com may have some insight

Comment: If you know it is in `AppData` you can dynamically get it right? why to set it in config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this in your configuration section :

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="xmlPath" value="C:/Users/Jonesy" />
</appSettings>
```

then in the code :

```
string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["xmlPath"];
```

you may need to add a reference to System.Configuration.